# Why does MSVC Linker (and lld-link) behave weirdly when entry point is manually set?

Tags: c, windows, linker, clang, lld

I was trying to compile a program in Windows using `clang` so that I can use cmdline options similar to `gcc` while statically linking to the UCRT library (`ucrt.lib`). Besides, I also want to specify the entry point to control when to initialize the runtime. Then I found some weird behaviors.

Take this snippet for example:

```
#include <memory.h>

char src[1000], dest[1000]; // Large enough to avoid inline memcpy

int main(void) {
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof (src));
//  memcpy_s(dest, sizeof (dest), src, sizeof (src));
    return 233;
}
```

Obviously, using normal options, it is okay to compile:

```
> clang test.c -Xlinker /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE -o test-llvm.exe
```

However, after specifying `/ENTRY`, `memcpy` (and some other library functions, if used) becomes undefined, quite like specifying `-nostdlib`.

```
> clang test.c -Xlinker /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE -Xlinker /ENTRY:main -o test-llvm.exe
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: memcpy
>>> referenced by ...\test.o:(main)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

We can manually add the library though, but the error is still there afterwards.

```
> clang test.c -lucrt -Xlinker /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE -Xlinker /ENTRY:main -o test-llvm.exe
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: memcpy
>>> referenced by ...\test.o:(main)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The strangest thing is, if I make the commented line back (`memcpy` not altered), the whole file will compile without problems.

```
> clang test-s.c -lucrt -Xlinker /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE -Xlinker /ENTRY:main -o test-llvm.exe
```

But why would `memcpy_s` affect the whole linking process? <s>Is that a bug?</s>
I have also tried changing the linker to LLD by `-fuse-ld=lld` and it produced identical results.

I once guessed it may be related to intrinsic functions, but adding options like `-fno-builtin` `-ffreestanding` doesn't change anything as well.

Comment: My next step to investigate would be to separate compiling from linking, and to look into the generated object files (with and without `memcpy_s`). The optimization level may have an effect, too. Did you try `-O0`? Please [edit] your question to add your findings.

Comment: @thebusybee No luck, adding `-O0` didn't affect the results at all. I will look into object or assembly files and update the question later.